# How do I Unmarshal complex nesting of yaml

Tags: go, yaml

How do I unmarshal this data?  I'm trying to extract the Name, Description, Version and other fields.  But when I print out the unmarshaled content I get the following:

> Index: {ApiVersion:v1 Entry:map[]
> Generated:2016-10-06T16:23:20.499029981-06:00}

Here is what I've tried so far.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

const index_yaml = `apiVersion: v1
entries:
    alpine:
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499814565-06:00
        description: Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod
        digest: 99c76e403d752c84ead610644d4b1c2f2b453a74b921f422b9dcb8a7c8b559cd
        home: https://helm.sh/helm
        name: alpine
        sources:
        - https://github.com/helm/helm
        urls:
        - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/alpine-0.2.0.tgz
        version: 0.2.0
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00
        description: Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod
        digest: 515c58e5f79d8b2913a10cb400ebb6fa9c77fe813287afbacf1a0b897cd78727
        home: https://helm.sh/helm
        name: alpine
        sources:
        - https://github.com/helm/helm
        urls:
        - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/alpine-0.1.0.tgz
        version: 0.1.0
    nginx:
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00
        description: Create a basic nginx HTTP server
        digest: aaff4545f79d8b2913a10cb400ebb6fa9c77fe813287afbacf1a0b897cdffffff
        home: https://helm.sh/helm
        name: nginx
        sources:
        - https://github.com/helm/charts
        urls:
        - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/nginx-1.1.0.tgz
        version: 1.1.0
generated: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499029981-06:00`

type Entry struct {
    Created     string `yaml:"created"`
    Description string `yaml:"created"`
    Home        string `yaml:"home"`
}

type Entries map[string][]Entry

type Index struct {
    ApiVersion string  `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Entry      Entries `yaml:"entry"`
    Generated  string  `yaml:"generated"`
}

func main() {
    // data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("index.yaml")
    // if err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal("Error reading index", err)
    //  return
    // }

    var index Index
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(index_yaml), &index)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("File reading error", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Index: %+v", index)
}
```

Comment: `Entry      Entries \`yaml:"entry"\`` should be `Entry      Entries \`yaml:"entries"\`` ? PS: kia ora :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is wonderfull service you can use to make struct for [your yamls](https://zhwt.github.io/yaml-to-go/). This is result of its work.

```golang
    type AutoGenerated struct {
        APIVersion string `yaml:"apiVersion"`
        Entries    struct {
            Alpine []struct {
                Created struct {
                } `yaml:"created"`
                Description string   `yaml:"description"`
                Digest      string   `yaml:"digest"`
                Home        string   `yaml:"home"`
                Name        string   `yaml:"name"`
                Sources     []string `yaml:"sources"`
                Urls        []string `yaml:"urls"`
                Version     string   `yaml:"version"`
            } `yaml:"alpine"`
            Nginx []struct {
                Created struct {
                } `yaml:"created"`
                Description string   `yaml:"description"`
                Digest      string   `yaml:"digest"`
                Home        string   `yaml:"home"`
                Name        string   `yaml:"name"`
                Sources     []string `yaml:"sources"`
                Urls        []string `yaml:"urls"`
                Version     string   `yaml:"version"`
            } `yaml:"nginx"`
        } `yaml:"entries"`
        Generated struct {
        } `yaml:"generated"`
    }

    var doc AutoGenerated
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(index_yaml), &doc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Doc: %+v", doc)
```

you can add `omitempty` where you need it, or change structure as you want it.

**update:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Entry struct {
    Created     string   `yaml:"created"`
    Description string   `yaml:"description"`
    Digest      string   `yaml:"digest"`
    Home        string   `yaml:"home"`
    Name        string   `yaml:"name"`
    Sources     []string `yaml:"sources"`
    Urls        []string `yaml:"urls"`
    Version     string   `yaml:"version"`
}

type AutoGenerated struct {
    APIVersion string             `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Entries    map[string][]Entry `yaml:"entries"`
    Generated  string             `yaml:"generated"`
}

func main() {

    var doc AutoGenerated
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(index_yaml), &doc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Doc: %+v", doc)

}

const index_yaml = `apiVersion: v1
entries:
  alpine:
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499814565-06:00
      description: Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod
      digest: 99c76e403d752c84ead610644d4b1c2f2b453a74b921f422b9dcb8a7c8b559cd
      home: https://helm.sh/helm
      name: alpine
      sources:
      - https://github.com/helm/helm
      urls:
      - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/alpine-0.2.0.tgz
      version: 0.2.0
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00
      description: Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod
      digest: 515c58e5f79d8b2913a10cb400ebb6fa9c77fe813287afbacf1a0b897cd78727
      home: https://helm.sh/helm
      name: alpine
      sources:
      - https://github.com/helm/helm
      urls:
      - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/alpine-0.1.0.tgz
      version: 0.1.0
  nginx:
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00
      description: Create a basic nginx HTTP server
      digest: aaff4545f79d8b2913a10cb400ebb6fa9c77fe813287afbacf1a0b897cdffffff
      home: https://helm.sh/helm
      name: nginx
      sources:
      - https://github.com/helm/charts
      urls:
      - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/nginx-1.1.0.tgz
      version: 1.1.0
generated: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499029981-06:00`
```

Comment: it's helpful but not suitable.  The name of the entry is arbitrary.  Not fixed to Alpine or Nginx... These are map[string] Entry I guess...

Comment: 1) then create https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2?utm_source=godoc#Unmarshaler for `Entries` struct type, that convert it to Entries

Comment: 2) or `map[interface{}]Entry` with entry describing node.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/H2T_pv1oNlH example with maps

Comment: Thanks, got it going now... I had the struct tag wrong... entry instead of entries!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to modify the indentation of your yaml input,then modify the `Entry      Entries` from `yaml:"entry"` to `yaml:"entries"` as per suggestion:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

const index_yaml = `apiVersion: v1
entries:
  alpine:
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499814565-06:00
      description: Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod
      digest: 99c76e403d752c84ead610644d4b1c2f2b453a74b921f422b9dcb8a7c8b559cd
      home: https://helm.sh/helm
      name: alpine
      sources:
      - https://github.com/helm/helm
      urls:
      - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/alpine-0.2.0.tgz
      version: 0.2.0
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00
      description: Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod
      digest: 515c58e5f79d8b2913a10cb400ebb6fa9c77fe813287afbacf1a0b897cd78727
      home: https://helm.sh/helm
      name: alpine
      sources:
      - https://github.com/helm/helm
      urls:
      - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/alpine-0.1.0.tgz
      version: 0.1.0
  nginx:
    - created: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00
      description: Create a basic nginx HTTP server
      digest: aaff4545f79d8b2913a10cb400ebb6fa9c77fe813287afbacf1a0b897cdffffff
      home: https://helm.sh/helm
      name: nginx
      sources:
      - https://github.com/helm/charts
      urls:
      - https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts/nginx-1.1.0.tgz
      version: 1.1.0
generated: 2016-10-06T16:23:20.499029981-06:00`

type Entry struct {
    Created     string `yaml:"created"`
    Description string `yaml:"description"`

    Home string `yaml:"home"`
}
type Entries map[string][]Entry

type Index struct {
    ApiVersion string  `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Entry      Entries `yaml:"entries"`
    Generated  string  `yaml:"generated"`
}

func main() {

    var index Index
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(index_yaml), &index)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("File reading error", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Index: %+v", index)

}
```

Output:

```
Index: {ApiVersion:v1 Entry:map[alpine:[{Created:2016-10-06T16:23:20.499814565-06:00 Description:Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod Home:https://helm.sh/helm} {Created:2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00 Description:Deploy a basic Alpine Linux pod Home:https://helm.sh/helm}] nginx:[{Created:2016-10-06T16:23:20.499543808-06:00 Description:Create a basic nginx HTTP server Home:https://helm.sh/helm}]] Generated:2016-10-06T16:23:20.499029981-06:00}
```